# Set timeout for expect script if execution time is input based

Tags: shell, scripting, tcl, expect

I have an expect script, which executes remote shell script.Now the time taken to execute shell script is based on inputs. More input, more time, less input less time.How should I set my timeout value because if set timeout as -1, then it will exit only with eof, and in case script gets hanged, then we will have a hanged session.

Comment: How those inputs read from the user ?

Comment: The input files are dynamically created and placed at the path from where the script reads them

Comment: Say, you are reading the inputs lines by line and for each line, try to increase the timeout value. Thus, more input, more timeout value.

Comment: But processing of these lines is not being done line by line , rather the remote script takes a batch of lines at a time and does the processing, also I cannot modify the remote script.

Comment: Do you have any way to estimate the amount of work that needs to be done? Or can you see some sort of progress indicators? Those could be used to reset the timeout (trivially with a little help from `exp_continue`).

Comment: @DonalFellows Thank you so much for your valuable suggestion.I used the progress indicators to reset my timeout counter using exp_continue and it solved my problem.
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Rinky, you might want to post an answer to your question. Otherwise is has no value to future readers and will be deleted.

Comment: @glenn jackman, Thanks for the suggestion. Have shared my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing the output pattern of the ongoing script, I found "OK" coming for all the lines read from the input file.So, I used it as a progress indicator to reset my timeout counter.
Following is the fraction of code I wrote to resolve my problem :

```
send -- "bash scriptname.sh \r"
expect {
         -re "OK" {
                  exp_continue
                  }
         -re "Enter XYZ value:" {
                                   send "0000\r"
                                   }
         timeout {
                 exit
                 }
         eof     {
                 exit
                 }
       }
```